# xslt: replace node values from generated table

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to anonymize telephone numbers in an xml document.
Numbers can occur multiple times and should always be replaced by the same value.

This is my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<somedata>
    <object>
        <nodeA>49123456789</nodeA>
        <nodeB>49123466666</nodeB>
    </object>
    <object>
        <nodeB>49987653333</nodeB>
    </object>
    <object>
        <nodeA>49123466666</nodeA>
    </object>
</somedata>
```

and this is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<somedata>
    <object>
        <nodeA>49123000001</nodeA>
        <nodeB>49123000002</nodeB>
    </object>
    <object>
        <nodeB>49987000003</nodeB>
    </object>
    <object>
        <nodeA>49123000002</nodeA>
    </object>
</somedata>
```

(note the second and last number)

I already have this working xslt to do the anonymizing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/" name="anonymize">

        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//nodeA | //nodeB)">
        <number>
            <old><xsl:value-of select="." /></old>
            <new><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,string-length(.)-6), format-number(position(), '000000'))"/></new>
        </number>
        </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am still looking for an easy way to replace the values. I found the xslt 3.0 map feature, but I would like to keep it to xslt 1.0 or 2.0 by now.

What would be the easiest way to get the desired output?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing your XML fragment in a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="phones">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//nodeA | //nodeB)">
        <number>
            <old><xsl:value-of select="." /></old>
            <new><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,string-length(.)-6), format-number(position(), '000000'))"/></new>
        </number>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then, when matching a `nodeA` or `nodeB` element, get the new number like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="$phones/number[old=current()]/new" />
```

This would be used in conjunction with the identity template to copy the other elements.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="phones">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//nodeA | //nodeB)">
        <number>
            <old><xsl:value-of select="." /></old>
            <new><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,string-length(.)-6), format-number(position(), '000000'))"/></new>
        </number>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="nodeA|nodeB">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$phones/number[old=current()]/new" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, use a key

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="phones" match="number" use="old" />

<xsl:variable name="phones">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//nodeA | //nodeB)">
        <number>
            <old><xsl:value-of select="." /></old>
            <new><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,string-length(.)-6), format-number(position(), '000000'))"/></new>
        </number>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="nodeA|nodeB">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('phones', ., $phones)/new" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, both solutions are XSLT 2.0 only.

Comment: thank you for your great answer! I have a small follow up question:  
The original xml has a namespace. If I add xpath-default-namespace to your xsl, both variants don't work for the original data. I assume that the variables don't match.  
Can you give me an idea how to fix this?

Comment: As well as xpath-default-namespace, you probably want to add a default namespace declaration to the creation of the `number` element; `<number xmlns="....">`